# Excel VBA -Insert image, but when I delete the image ind the explorer it dissapears in the excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

The code works (sort of), but when I've inserted the image, I save the excel file and delete the foto in the file explorer. Then when I open then excel file again the image is gone.

```
Sub InsertImage()
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .ButtonName = "Submit"
        .Title = "Select an image file"
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "JPG", "*.JPG"
        .Filters.Add "JPEG File Interchange Format", "*.JPEG"
        .Filters.Add "Graphics Interchange Format", "*.GIF"
        .Filters.Add "Portable Network Graphics", "*.PNG"
        .Filters.Add "Tag Image File Format", "*.TIFF"
        .Filters.Add "All Pictures", "*.*"

        If .Show = -1 Then
            Dim img As Object
            Set img = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(.SelectedItems(1))

            'Scale image size
            'img.ShapeRange.ScaleWidth 0.75, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
            'img.ShapeRange.ScaleHeight 0.75, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft

            'Position image
            img.Left = 300
            img.Top = 200

            'Set image sizes in points
            img.Width = 150
            img.Height = 150
        Else
            MsgBox ("Programet blev Annulleret")
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Isn't there a way to make the picture save with the excel file? So when I delete the original picture it is still in the excel file.

The error I get "The linked image cannot be displayed. The file may have been moved, renamed, or deleted. Verify that the link points to the correct file and location.

Comment: use [`Shapes.AddPicture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/shapes-addpicture-method-excel) with the second criteria as `False`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The picture is being inserted as a linked image, if you want the image to be saved in the excel spreadsheet you'll want it to be an embedded image

```
Sub InsertImage()

    Dim FullPathName as string

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .ButtonName = "Submit"
        .Title = "Select an image file"
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "JPG", "*.JPG"
        .Filters.Add "JPEG File Interchange Format", "*.JPEG"
        .Filters.Add "Graphics Interchange Format", "*.GIF"
        .Filters.Add "Portable Network Graphics", "*.PNG"
        .Filters.Add "Tag Image File Format", "*.TIFF"
        .Filters.Add "All Pictures", "*.*"

        If .Show = -1 Then
            '''''' Store the pathname of selected image to a variable
            FullPathName = .SelectedItems(1)

            '''''' Imports image as embedded into Worksheet
            Activesheet.Shapes.AddPicture filename:=FullPathName, _
            linktofile:=msoFalse, savewithdocument:=msoCTrue, _
            left:=300, _
            top:=200, _
            width:=150, _
            height:=150

            Dim Pic As shape
            For Each Pic In ActiveSheet.Shapes
               ''''' Change "A1" to which ever cell this is being placed in
               'If (Pic.left = Range("A1").left And Pic.top = Range("A1").top) Then
                  Pic.Select
                  Pic.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
               'End If
            Next Pic

        Else
            MsgBox ("Programet blev Annulleret")
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Not a problem, please mark as answered so others can solve similar issues

Comment: Although, I seen to have a problem altering the aspect ratio. Is there a way to make it so the picture keeps it's original aspect ratio?

Comment: @oscarkjaer Yes, Just add `img.Shaperange.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue` some where before the `Else` statement

Comment: '''''' Imports image as embedded into Worksheet        
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture Filename:=FullPathName, _
        linktofile:=msoFalse, savewithdocument:=msoCTrue, _
        Left:=300, _
        Top:=200, _
        Width:=150, _
        Height:=150

        img.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
           
        Else
            MsgBox ("Programet blev Annulleret")
    End If

Comment: That's it yup! :)

Comment: But... It still doesn't work, well it works, I get an error, and then it inserts the picture. Although still with a fixed aspect ratio.

I'm really sorry, I must be a hassle

Comment: Run-time error '91':

Object variable or With block variable not set

Comment: They look exactly the same now, yes

Comment: Ah I see why, so in order to lock it, you'll have to select it... Unfortunately it's a little difficult to select it unless you know the exact name of the image at time of import. Fortunately, if this is the only image, it can be quite simple. Is this the only image that is being inserted? If not, is it ok to keep the Aspect Ratio locked on ALL images? Or if it's being placed in the same spot everytime

Comment: Well, it is going to be the only one when importing, so I guess it's okay to keep the Aspect Ratio locked on ALL images. It is also oing to placed on the same spot when importing, although it will be moved around after it has been insereted into the spreadsheet. :)

Comment: @oscarkjaer See my edit in the code above, managed to get it working... Tested it myself and it's working. Just remove the commented out `IF THEN` statement if you want to specify the range that it's imported to

Comment: For some reason it is still not working for me. I'll just let it be as it is, as it somehow won't form properly... Thanks for your help nevertheless ;)